# how to disable an option already selected in another <select>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, magento-1.7

I have five HTML `selects` with different values, but the options have the same text. How do I compare the text options, instead of the values, and disable the the respective option in every other select? For example, if I have:

```
<select name="options[70]" id="select_70">
  <option value="1" price="0"> test-1 </option>
  <option value="2" price="0"> test-2 </option>
  <option value="3" price="0"> test-3 </option>
</select>
<select name="options[71]" id="select_71">
  <option value="4" price="0"> test-1 </option>
  <option value="5" price="0"> test-2 </option>
  <option value="6" price="0"> test-3 </option>
</select>
<select name="options[72]" id="select_72">
  <option value="7" price="0"> test-1 </option>
  <option value="8" price="0"> test-2 </option>
  <option value="9" price="0"> test-3 </option>
</select>
<select name="options[73]" id="select_73">
  <option value="10" price="0"> test-1 </option>
  <option value="11" price="0"> test-2 </option>
  <option value="12" price="0"> test-3 </option>
</select>
<select name="options[74]" id="select_74">
  <option value="13" price="0"> test-1 </option>
  <option value="14" price="0"> test-2 </option>
  <option value="15" price="0"> test-3 </option>
</select>
```

Suppose the user selects the option `test-1` in the last `select`. This should disable the corresponding `option` in the other selects. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707850/3-dropdown-populate-based-on-selection-in-another-cascading-dropdown/16708479#16708479

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you properly, this might be it:

```
var $selects = $('select');
$selects.on('change', function() {
    var $select = $(this), 
        $options = $selects.not($select).find('option'),
        selectedText = $select.children('option:selected').text();

    var $optionsToDisable = $options.filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == selectedText;
    });

    $optionsToDisable.prop('disabled', true);
});

//to apply initial selection
$selects.eq(0).trigger('change');
```

jsFiddle: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jc2C5/4/)

Comment: Seems like a good answer to me, I'd probably take a similar approach. Only thing I'd note is that you seem to like using the `$` to denote jQuery objects, but your `selects` variable hasn't got one. Also I think you could probably do the filtering a little cleaner by using an each just once.

Comment: Why are you confused with the downvotes? Your code doesn't work. Try selecting "test-2" in the second dropdown, then selecting "test-3" in the third dropdown. When you view the 4th dropdown, you're able to select "test-2"...why is that? Also, why the heck are you using `$($selects.get(0))`? Ever heard of `.eq()`?

Comment: @IanClark `but your selects variable hasn't got one.` - What are you talking about? `$selects, `$select`, `$options`, and `$optionsToDisable` are all jQuery objects.

Comment: @Ian, thank, seems that i didn't get the point, now it should work as expected, though it doesn't make any sense since you can't select anything after selecting test-1, test-2 and test-3 in different dropdowns

Comment: `Ian` I know, I'm saying that if you're using the dollar sign to distinguish jQuery objects then you should be consistent.

Comment: @Ian, also I fixed variables names after IanClark's comment

Comment: @IgorDymov I agree, seems a bit silly what happens after all 3 are selected. Looks good though :)

Comment: @IanClark I see, my bad :) I thought I remembered always seeing them all have the `$` (I saw the many edits). Good point about consistency though :)

Comment: @IgorDymov check my answer to see what you think, might be worth taking from it as this answer is now the accepted one?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @IgorDymov's answer (credit should go to him), here's probably what I'd do (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jc2C5/6/)):

```
var $selects = $('select');
$selects.on('change', function() {
    $("option", $selects).prop("disabled", false);
    $selects.each(function() {
        var $select = $(this), 
            $options = $selects.not($select).find('option'),
            selectedText = $select.children('option:selected').text();
        $options.each(function() {
            if($(this).text() == selectedText) $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        });
    });
});

$selects.eq(0).trigger('change');
```

That way we completely refresh the selections each time a new one is made, which means properties become re-enabled again. You'll notice in the fiddle I reduced the number of selects and increased the number of options so that you don't get trapped in a situation where all options are disabled at the same time, I think that makes most sense.

Comment: this is excellent, but how do i amend this to only be certain selects. i have 9 selects but only want it applied on 3 of them. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

A length example

```
var $selects = $('select');
available = {};

// Get the text of options from the dropdown
// and store in a object hash 
$('option', $selects.eq(0)).each(function (i) {
    var val = $.trim($(this).text());
    available[val] = false;
});

$selects.change(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var selectedVal = $.trim($this.find('option:selected').text());

    // set that value to true
    available[selectedVal] = true;

    $selects.not(this).each(function () {
        $('option', this).each(function () {
            var optText = $.trim($(this).text()),
                optCheck = available[optText];

            $(this).prop('disabled', optCheck );
        });
    });
}).change(); // Trigger once to add options at load of first choice
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/KyGbx/)**

Comment: you may just do `$(this).prop('disabled', optCheck);` instead of `if-else` block

Answer (score -1):

To get the text in between the option tags of the currently selected option you would do this:

```
$('option[value="'+$('select').val()+'"]').text();
```

it translates to: get text of option with a value that is the same as the currently listed value in the select